# Need to find annual payment in 2 halfs of the payment period

Tags: finance, economics

A loan of $4000 is to be repaid over a period of 8 years. During the first years, exactly half of the loan principal is to be repaid (along with accumulated compound interest) by a uniform series of payments A1 dollar per year. The other half of the loan principal is to be repaid over four years with accumulated interest by a uniform series of A2 dollar per year. If interest rate=9% per year what are A1 and A2?

In the book answers are:

A1=797.47
A2=617.4

Comment: How many are the first years? When do begin the other four years?

Comment: 4 years for the first half and 4 years for the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $L_1=L_2=2000,\,L=L_1+L_2=4000, \, i=9\%,\,n_1=n_2=4,\, n=n_1+n_2=8$.

The loan $L$ during the first $n_1$ years will produce the amount $S_1=L(1+i)^{n_1}=5643.33$ and the interest over the first $n_1$ years is $I_1=S_1-L=1643.33$.

So at the end of the $n_1$-th year we have to repay the value $FV_1=L_1+I_1=3643.33$ with a uniform stream of payments $A_1$ such that
$$
FV_1(i,n_1,A_1) = A_1 \times s_{\overline{n_1}\!|i} \quad \text{where}\quad s_{\overline{n_1}\!|i} =\frac{(1+i)^{n_1}-1}{i}
$$
and so we find $A_1=797.34$.

Over the $n_2$ years we have to repay the loan $L_2=PV_2(i,n_2,A_2)$ as the present value of a stream of payments satisfying the annuity relation
$$
PV_2(i,n_1,A_1) = A_2 \times a_{\overline{n_2}\!|i} \quad \text{where}\quad a_{\overline{n_2}\!|i} =\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n_2}}{i}
$$
that is $A_2=617.34$.